# How are electric current X-Y coordinates achieved for each individual pixel in a monochrome LCD display?

Tags: display, monitor

I took apart a simple blue monochrome LCD and layed out all the layers as pictured below.

Just looking at them, I am confused as to which of these layers is responsible for turning the current on/off for each individual pixel? And how does it specify the precise x-y coordinates for where specifically the current gets turned on/off?

I feel like I am missing something. Are there actual physical current conductor paths laid out going to each pixel individually in one of these layers? Which?

[image]

Comment: The conductors are internal to the LCD panel itself (black thing in your picture).

Comment: https://www.edn.com/how-an-lcd-controller-drives-an-lcd-glass/

Comment: @user1850479 so both the crystals and the conductors are sandwiched in the same layer? Are the conductors basically invisible? because when I peel off the black film from the lcd glass sandwich itself, the glass is perfectly clear.

Comment: It would make sense to need transparent conductors if they run all over the LCD glass

Comment: These conductors on the glass used to be made from ITO - indium tin oxide, they might still be as well. If you get glare at just right angle on the coated side you can see the layout.

Comment: just playing with the display i discovered that if i quickly peel off one of the polarizing films from one side while looking through the other side of the glass, you can momentarily see the circuit layout. the film stays sticky so you can repeat this quickly - stick on and remove - and visualize the circuitry :) Thanks everyone!

Comment: per above method, i can clearly see that the circuitry isn't just individual pixels for this simple display. Many of the icons that were persistent on the working display (like a wifi icon) get its own full circuit "stamp" so you're not programming individual pixels on the backend to turn on/off -  current is just supplied/cutoff to the entire icon "stamp" to illuminate it...which makes sense for a simpler display without much dynamic content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, the display is a segmented LCD.

So the addressable elements are not small pixels arranged in grid of rows and columns, but larger areas of symbols and icons engraved in the glass, such as individual segments of a 7 segment digit.

Comment: thanks. curious, how is current conducted to each individual segment?

Comment: You have that answered already in the comments. With conductive wiring layer made of indium tin oxide, almost like how PCBs have wiring layer made of copper.